# linear constraint on binary variable

Tags: constraints

I have to make a linear constraint for a binary variable in the following way.

We have a set $S=\{0,1,\dots,k\}$ and the binary variable $b$ is defined as:

$$b=\begin{cases} 
      1 & if\;S=1,\\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}
.$$

I couldn't manage to create the constraints for this relation to hold.

Comment: This makes no sense. Do wish to have the variable attain the value $1$ if $S$ contains only the singleton $\{1 \}$?